# Using Opera 21.9 how do I shut down auto-refresh

Tags: opera, system-preferences

I recently switched to Opera. But it does one thing I can't stand. It automatically refreshes a page.
Something like Twitter, where I have to scroll through many tweets, getting refreshed and bumped back up to the top tweet is really annoying.
I have seen advice that says go to preferences and turn on auto-redirection... expect that with the version of Opera I have (21.0) that option seems to be gone.
HELP